# Debugging a Remotely-located Aggregate in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, clr, aggregate-functions

So I'm having a big problem. I need to debug a custom aggregate, and I'm able to build and deploy it, but once it's going, it won't allow the following:

1. Administrator access under any circumstances.
2. `File.Write` access (no writting text files)
3. `EventLog` access.
4. `Remote Debugging` access because of a complex firewall, user-rights, et al.
5. Getting data through a local installation of `SQL Server`. I have data stored in one remote location, and I'm not able to dump it for testing.

How would I debug a custom aggregate in this scenario? When trying to use `File.Write`, or `EventLog.WriteEvent`, it throws a security access exception.

Is there a way to print the output as it happens during each aggregate function call? I want to know what's being pumped and dumped into `Merge()`, `Terminate()`, etc., as it's happening.

Is there something I'm missing? Thanks.

Comment: [`SqlPipe.Send`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127319(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

Comment: Just tried that. `A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate[...]`, `System.InvalidOperationException: Data access is not allowed in this context[...]`

Comment: Yeah… there's no `DataAccessKind` property in the `SqlUserDefinedAggregateAttribute` class, so you can't set it. Unfortunately, I can't think of another method to get a peek in given the restrictions you've stated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given these difficult access restrictions, we were able to come up with a solution. It's not perfect, but it gives us the output we needed.

Our solution was to create a `StringBuilder` instance.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuidlder();
```

And add stuff to it where necessary to debug:

```
sb.Append("|Debug information");
```

At the end, we append the `StringBuilder` to the collection result. Instead of getting back "test," we'd get back something like this:

```
"test|debug information|more debug information|more debug information."
```

And then we'd copy that information, and use it for debugging. It's not perfect, but we were able to separate the results by splitting them, and get the job done.